# Android: Is it the right approach to convert JSON to POJO?

Tags: android, json, rest, android-volley, pojo

I'm using Volley Library to get JSON responses on my requests. I created base http Helper classes which process requests and return JSON for next processing.

I would like to ask what is the right approach to process returned JSON data?

I would like to use data for displaying in `ListView`, `View`, etc. but I don't know what is the right approach (Convert to POJO or keep data in JSON?)

I tried to find any solution on this topic:
[Json to POJO mapping in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465523/json-to-pojo-mapping-in-android)

But it seems that each object should have a single class with definition of the all possible fields of the object.

This approach seems strange to me because I have already created models for the database objects and if JSON object is changed (for example added new attribute or changed his name) it means that code on the API models should be changed too.

Is there any other possibility and the right way how to avoid this and work with returned data only in  Activities (Controllers)?

Comment: u can reuse the json model in db or db model with json

Comment: They structures are quite differrent and not all JSON entities has equivalent in DB models. I don't think that is good idea to mix DB models with JSON entities because i think that is causing mess in the app logic.

Comment: there is no harm in making different pojo for both or else if minor diffrance then u can use transient keywork for non json key

Comment: Now you can use [link](https://github.com/robohorse/RoboPOJOGenerator) to generate POJO inside android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GSON](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) it is quite snappy and easy to use. for e.g.

```
Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
 MyType target = new MyType();
 String json = gson.toJson(target); // serializes target to Json
MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```

Answer (score 1):

Read my answer completely, i've explained in easy way.

First of all if you are using Volley no need of http helper class, use Volley's method to get JSON data by objects or array.

Second POJO classes are best use it. yes it is the right approach.

Here is the source code to get json object data from volley and store in POJO.

/**
 * Method to make json object request where json response starts wtih {
 * */
private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
        "http://api.example.com", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    // Parsing json object response
                    // response will be a json object
                    String name = response.getString("name");
                    String email = response.getString("email");

                    //POJO class to store
                    Person person = new Person();
                    person.name=name;
                    person.email=email;                        

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the progress dialog
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

}

Comment: I would move the parsing logic away from onResponse, since this method is executed on the main thread.

Comment: that's just an small example so i placed the parsing logic there itself

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest you transform JSON to POJOs and use this. It is much more natural to use objects to represent data in an object oriented language, such as Java.

> I would like to ask what is the right approach to processing returned JSON data?

There are two main options:

1. Use the built - in JSON SDK - it is a very decent tool and is adequate if you don't have complex response structures. It can be quite performant.
2. Use some kind of a third party JSON processing library - GSON or Jackson. They come stacked with functionality, like automatic deserialisation from JSON to POJO based on annotations, etc. This can save you time, but it is expensive. To get the best performance out of this, you should still parse the things manually, but you can start doing this only if you need to optimise.

No matter what you use, just make sure that JSON processing is done on a worker thread. If you are using Volley, you should consider extending a Request class and overriding parseNetworkResponse() - this is a good place to plug in your deserialisation. The responses will now be POJOs and you can use them to populate lists, etc.

As far as this goes:

> This approach seems to me strange because i have already created models for the database objects and if JSON object is changed (for example added new attribute or changed his name) it means that code on the API models should be changed too.

Unfortunately, you are right. But this is a common problem in client - server communication. When using JSON over HTTP there is no way to enforce that the contract between server and client is being followed. The best you could do, IMHO, is detect the possible exceptions and handle them accordingly - showing a message to the user, or something like that. You can always use Maps to hold the deserialised payload as key - value pairs, but this doesn't really solve the issue, but ensures the deserialisation logic wont' fail.