# How to bypass `null` values in JSON?

Tags: android, json

How can I bypass an empty `JSON` value and give it a default value.
**This is my code:**

```
private static Cursor extractFeatureFromJson(String foodJSON) {
    // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(foodJSON)) {
        return null;
    }

    try {

        JSONArray foodArray = new JSONArray(foodJSON);

        for (int i = 0; i < foodArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject foodObject = foodArray.getJSONObject(i);

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_NDB_NO, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_NDB_NO));
            values.put(COLUMN_NAME, foodObject.getString(COLUMN_NAME));
            values.put(COLUMN_WATER_G, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_WATER_G));
            values.put(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL));
            values.put(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G));
            values.put(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G));
            values.put(COLUMN_ASH_G, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_ASH_G));
            values.put(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G));

            foodNutriProvider insert = new foodNutriProvider();

            insert.insert(CONTENT_URI,values);

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Log.e("foodSearch", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
        Log.e("foodSearch", foodJSON);
    }

    foodNutriProvider getTable = new foodNutriProvider();

    Cursor foodTable = getTable.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    return foodTable;
}
```

The app crashes whenever it faces an `empty` field and for my app it doesn't really matter if its empty and I can give it a `0` instead.

Comment: Best practise is you should have to do null checks,

Comment: what about a check for null by using if condition?

Comment: You can create a POJO with default value and use that, instead of your JSON directly. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13466012/2520628

Comment: if(!value = null){ //Do some action here}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using **getInt** or **getString** with JSONObject , I will suggest you to use **optInt** or **optString** and it will automatically handle the null pointer exception for you and they are JSONObject internal method.

I have just replaced all getInt and getString with optInt and optString in your code, so request you to please check and let me know if this works for you.

Also, request you to please cross check the json data type you are trying to fetch from response. Like you are trying to fetch string and you are using getInt.

```
 private static Cursor extractFeatureFromJson(String foodJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(foodJSON)) {
            return null;
        }

        try {

            JSONArray foodArray = new JSONArray(foodJSON);

            for (int i = 0; i < foodArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject foodObject = foodArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(COLUMN_NDB_NO, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_NDB_NO));
                values.put(COLUMN_NAME, foodObject.optString(COLUMN_NAME));
                values.put(COLUMN_WATER_G, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_WATER_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL));
                values.put(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_ASH_G, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_ASH_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G));

                foodNutriProvider insert = new foodNutriProvider();

                insert.insert(CONTENT_URI,values);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

            Log.e("foodSearch", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
            Log.e("foodSearch", foodJSON);
        }

        foodNutriProvider getTable = new foodNutriProvider();

        Cursor foodTable = getTable.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        return foodTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your app crashes with NUll Pointer error. If so, you must do a check for null values by using if condition.

Comment: what error do you get? and from which line? please try to be a bit specific.

Answer (score 0):

For JSONObject :- foodJSONObject.isNull()

For JSONArray  :- foodJSONArray.isNull(index)

For Getting values from a key :- foodJSONObject.optString("KEY_PARAMETER")

Comment: if(foodObject.optString(COLUMN_WATER_G)==null){
                    values.put(COLUMN_WATER_G, 0);
                }else{
                    values.put(COLUMN_WATER_G, foodObject.getInt(COLUMN_WATER_G));
                } this didnt work

Comment: you need to use
 if(foodObject.optString(COLUMN_WATER).isNullorBlank()){
  //****your code
}